# Does Java List behave as a covariant type during initialisation?

Tags: java, list, generics, covariance

I know that Lists in Java are Invariant.

So the second statement below gives a compilation error as expected

```
    List<Integer> integers = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
    List<Number> numbers = integers;
```

However, all of these work fine

```
    List<Integer> numbers1 = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
    List<? extends Number> numbers2 = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
    List<Number> numbers3 = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
```

So my question is how does the last statement above compile?

I understand that `Arrays.asList()` accepts the type from its caller, but I thought `Arrays.asList(1,2,3)` whould resolve to the closest type `List<Integer>` and setting it to `List<Number>` would not compile, since Lists are Invariant.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no covariance going on here. Instead, Java compiler uses the context of the call to `Arrays.asList<T>` to *infer* the type `T` that your program wanted to specify for the method call.

Prior to Java 8 you could specify the type explicitly, for example

```
List<Integer> numbers1 = Arrays.<Integer>asList(1, 2, 3);
List<? extends Number> numbers2 = Arrays.<? extends Number>asList(1, 2, 3);
List<Number> numbers3 = Arrays.<Number>asList(1, 2, 3);
```

Noting how the above code snippets repeat the type `T` on both sides of the assignment, Java compiler set up inference rules to propagate `T` from the left side of the assignment to the right side, eliminating the repetition.

Reference: [*Type Inference Tutorial*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html).

Comment: "Java 8 implemented type inference based on the target type". It is not exact. Before Java 8, it was already based on the target type The inference feature "only" was improved.

Answer (score 1):

The JLS illustrates very well this case.
This is not covariance during initialization as it will also work in "classic" method invocations.
Note that the inference strategy used in your example make it work in Java 8 but it would fail in Java 7.

> [**18.5.2. Invocation Type Inference**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-18.html#jls-18.5.2)
>
> Consider the example from the previous section:
>
> `List<Number> ln = Arrays.asList(1, 2.0);`
>
> The most specific applicable method was identified as:
>
> `public static <T> List<T> asList(T... a)`
>
> In order to complete type-checking of the method invocation, we must determine whether it
>   is compatible with its target type, `List<Number>`.
>
> The bound set used to demonstrate applicability in the previous
>   section, B2, was:
>
> `{ α <: Object, Integer <: α, Double <: α }`
>
> The new constraint formula set is as follows:
>
> `{ ‹List<α> → List<Number>› }`
>
> This compatibility constraint produces an equality bound for α, which
>   is included in the new bound set, B3:
>
> `{ α <: Object, Integer <: α, Double <: α, α = Number }`
>
> These bounds are trivially resolved:
>
> `α = Number`
>
> Finally, we perform a substitution on the declared return type of
>   asList to determine that the method invocation has type List;
>   clearly, this is compatible with the target type.
>
> This inference strategy is different than the Java SE 7 Edition of The
>   Java® Language Specification, which would have instantiated α based on
>   its lower bounds (before even considering the invocation's target
>   type), as we did in the previous section. This would result in a type
>   error, since the resulting type is not a subtype of List.

Answer (score 0):

B/c the Number is superclass of these subclasses:

Direct Known Subclasses:
AtomicInteger, AtomicLong, BigDecimal, BigInteger, Byte, Double, DoubleAccumulator, DoubleAdder, Float, Integer, Long, LongAccumulator, LongAdder, Short

Source: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html

In your first code snippet you're adding "fruits" to the basket of "apples" (you cannot do it!), in your second case, this isn't true.

Comment: Obviously, OP understands this. His question is about the type `T` in `Arrays.asList<T>`

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - understood - added just one sentence

Comment: I don't think this sentence is right though. In the first example he's saying "here, this basket of apples is a basket of fruits". It's problematic because you could then add any fruit to the basket which is still though as a basket of apples by the other reference, but I don't remember the exact mechanism that forbids this and why it doesn't matter in the second case.

Comment: @Aaron, I see what you mean, but IF T extends K, it doesn't mean that LIST<T> extends LIST<K>. Or, maybe I'm totally wrong? I'll delete this answer if it isn't true...

Comment: Alright, I see what you meant (and yeah that's correct). Your last sentence is misleading though since OP isn't adding anything to any List.

Comment: @Aaron Should I delete my answer? I've never cared about the rating, I admit my "so called" answers (every one of them) is (was) based on common logic,,,

Comment: It's up to you really ; I don't think your answer really address OP's concerns, but it's not factually incorrect either and might help others wandering here.

Answer (score 0):

Granted, `Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3)` yields a `List<Integer>`.
Then, `List<Integer>` is a valid `List<? extends Number>`. You can prove this to yourself:

```
List<? extends Number> l1 = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> l2 = new ArrayList<>();
l1 = l2;
```

However the contrary is indeed not true:

```
l2 = l1; // does not compile
```

`Integer` is a subclass of `Number` so `List<Integer>` is a valid `List` of things that extends `Number`.